# Anyway to put workbook activate and deactivate in the worksheet object?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there anyway to put the workbook/worksheet activate/deactivate sub routine into the sheet of the worksheet rather then having it on the "ThisWorkbook" section?

I have a form that I want to activate and deactivate when I switch between workbooks without having that form show on all workbooks. I currently have it working having the activate/deactivate in the "ThisWorkbook" section but would like to know if there is a way to have the code located in the Sheets section.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including code, and what you are trying to accomplish. It is also helpful to know what version of Excel you are using. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Good job, I think this is a perfectly reasonable question now after looking back at the edit. Maybe the downvoter will come back and change it. It does need some clarification though.

Comment: So right now when you click on, say, book2 sheet2, a form pops up? Why would it pop up when you do something in book1? Is it a target? What event fires it?

Comment: it fires because I have the modal set to false so it stays on the workbook sheet at all times, but when I switch workbook I dont' want to see the form for that particular workbook/sheet. Right now it works fine if the code is located in the "ThisWorkbook" but if it is moved to a sheet code object, it does work, was just wondering if there is a way to move the code to a sheet so that it works there as well.